# XSL finding and transforming attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with data inside attributes, simply one attribute in a generic element.

```
<main>
  <tag aaa="p1"/>
  <tag aaa="p2"/>
  <tag bbb="p3"/>
</main>
```

I want to use XSL to change the attributes into elements, so in this example I would get the following:

```
<main>
  <aaa>p1</aaa>
  <aaa>p2</aaa>
  <bbb>p3</bbb>
</main>
```

I don't know the attribute names in advance;  I want to generically do this for any such attribute name.
The rest of the structure is constant - one attribute in one  element.

How can I catch and transform all such attributes?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, show your XSLT code. If no, why not?

Comment: This is a simple (probably) part of XSLT which one i don't know how to do. I had an idea about regular expressions (like aaa|bbb) and text insert to create tags, but I think it won't work

Comment: It's not only simple, it's fundamental.  Go for it!  -1 until you try it and come up with a specific technical question.  Here's google-ing for many online xsl test pages: https://www.google.com/search?q=run+xsl+online&oq=run+xsl+online

Comment: @Denis Here's a hint. Make an `<xsl:template>` that uses `<xsl:element>` and `@*[1]` creatively.

Comment: And most of them translate to arbitrary tags, but not specified. And I'm still searching

Comment: Follow the direction of @Tomalak ...  it is not at all necessary to know the exact name of a tag to access it.   Hmmmm... or is maybe that a more specific question to ask.

Comment: Edited the question as such ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update : To get this to work in a generic + nested stucture (and assuming that there is a fixed root element), starting off with `identity` and to process the attributes of each element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::*]">
      <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
         <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms:

```
<main>
   <tag aaa="p1">
      <nestedtag a1="xx" a2="yy"></nestedtag>
   </tag>
   <moretag aaa="p2"/>
   <anothertag bbb="p3"/>
</main>
```

To:

```
<main>
   <aaa>p1</aaa>
      <a1>xx</a1><a2>yy</a2>
   <aaa>p2</aaa>
   <bbb>p3</bbb>
</main>
```

Comment: @Denis I've updated to address this in a more generic + nested fashion?